# Add value to a key that already has values python dict

Tags: python

Say my dictionary has a key House with the value dog

How can I add a value cat to my key house so that the dictionary would show House: dog, cat

Comment: `d['House'] = d['House'] + ", cat"` Just pull the previous values and concat the new value.

Comment: `my_dict['House'] = ('dog', 'cat')` ?

Comment: Make the value a *list* which can hold several values‽

Answer (score 3):

You can point house to list of animals.

```
my_dict['house'] = ['dog']
#then add cat to list
my_dict['house'].append('cat')
```

Comment: Depending on the usecase, I would start off using `my_dict = defaultdict(list)`